# PHP ZF2: Class not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've got a problem with finding a class. I am using ZF2, and I have ElephantIO under \public\lib. Netbeans finds the class I am trying to use, and it points me to it when I type "use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version0X;"...

However when I run the code in my localhost, it returns Class 'ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version0X' not found in /Applications/MA....

I am calling it in

```
new Version0X('http://localhost:5555');
```

I can also access it using NetBeans' Open declaration.

What seems to be the problem?

More:
I tried adding a require_once for the Version0X php file and it did work, but then it told me that another class which extends Version0X isn't found, so I guessed this will be too much trouble to add all files.

Comment: Sounds like your autoloader can't find that class (and related classes). I'm not familiar with ZF2's autoloading. Does it use composer?

Comment: Thanks, this led me to stop using copy paste and start using composer for real!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it wasn't accessible from public/lib, so I used composer to install it in vendor. That is all it has needed.